# HTTP POST from a ASP.NET MVC Ajax form does not include submit buttons

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am unable to determine which form submit button is clicked during an Ajax Form POST in ASP.NET MVC.  I have a form that basically looks like:

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit",
                             new { code = Model.Code },
                             new AjaxOptions() {
                                UpdateTargetId = "resultsDiv"
                             })) {%>
    <p>
       <%= Html.TextBox("Name", Model.Name)%>         

       <input id="submitButton1" name="submitAction" class="ajaxSubmitButton"
              type="submit" value="Button 1" />
       <input id="submitButton2" name="submitAction" class="ajaxSubmitButton" 
              type="submit" value="Button 2" />

       <input id="testHiddenValue" name="testHiddenValue" 
              type="hidden" value="hello world!" />
    </p>

<% } %>
```

After a standard HTTP POST (ie. JavaScript disabled), I get access to the following POST variables:

- Name = whatever
- submitAction = Button 1
- testHiddenValue = hello world!

However, clicking that button with JavaScript enabled does not include the submitAction value.  I have verified this by inspecting the POSTs with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

My hunch is that the Microsoft Ajax library just doesn't serialize the values of the submit buttons.  In any case, how can I get around this so my controller knows which button was clicked?

---

**Edit:** Yes, it looks like a bug in the Microsoft Ajax library (see below).  To workaround this, I essentially added the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {           
    $("#formId .ajaxSubmitButton").live("click", function() {                
        $("#testHiddenValue").attr("value", $(this).attr("value"));
    });    
});
```

Then in my controller, if `Request.IsAjaxRequest() == true`, I can check the value of #testHiddenValue.  Otherwise, I can look in `Request.Form["submitAction"]` and determine the correct course of action from there.

Fairly clunky, but I can't really see an alternative.

Comment: does this approach work if it were a regular form as opposed to an ajax form?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I assume so.  It works when you disable JavaScript.  A similar suggestion (for a regular form) is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787523/asp-net-mvc-ajax-beginform-eats-params-of-submit-button-clicked-looks-like-bug). It looks like this is a bug. Personally I would investigate injecting the button name you wish to know about into a hidden form field as a temporary fix.

Comment: I guess it is Microsoft's bug.  Injecting the button name into a hidden field is exactly the workaround I had planned.  I will edit my original post with the code when I have it.